# Rails: How to not use LESS for flatui and bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use casual css or maybe scss for bootstrap/flatui generates. However, my generated `bootstrap:install` and `flatuipro:install` produces a `.less` files. I have many problems with .less such as window version of `therubyracer` wreck my rails page, so I don't want to use it.

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=mybook_rails_4_0
gem 'rails'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'pg'
end

gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier'

gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'designmodo-flatuipro-rails', '1.1.3.1'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'angularjs-rails'

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Here is the command I used to generate bootstrap and flatuipro

```
rails g bootstrap:install
rails g flatuipro:install <flatui-directory>
```

Here is the files created in `assets/stylesheet`

```
flatuipro.less
bootstrap_and_override.css.less
```

Comment: doesnt look like theres a sass version quite yet https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI-Pro-Support/issues/16

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I switched to `rails g bootstrap:install static`, which doesn't depend on less anymore... sad story, I'll have to rollback to basic css bootstraps